# Creating sample multi-TB databases with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

For reasons I won't go into I need to do some tests with sample terabyte-sized databases in Postgres. Those tests are *not* your typical SQL-level benchmark tests, more like tests of how quickly I can back the database up, restore it, etc, so while test DBs should have some structure, it's not really important what those structures are as long as there's minimum complexity to them like a few tables.

The requirement is that tested databases have at least 10TB size, preferably 20TB, size being understood as diskspace occupied by database files (yes it should be size after vacuuming etc).

So I'm trying to use `pgbench` tool to generate such sample databases. I started pgbench with intention of creating 15TB DB like this:

`pgbench -i -s 1600000 pgbench15t`

So this run has generated tuples in like 3 days, but now `pgbench` is hanging on vacuuming for like 2 days by now. What's worse, there does not seem to be much activity with either `postmaster` process or disk (I tested that with `iotop`).

Note: PG version is 11 (I'm not at liberty to choose version) and I've used default settings. Can that be a problem (i.e. default settings)?

OK so I have two main questions:

1. Is there some other quick way of generating such sample TB-sized databases that would not involve me just writing DB generation script / program?
2. Can `pgbench` be used in some specific way that would result in successful generation of say 15TB DB?

Comment: If pgbench "hangs" on the vacuuming part, did you try to run it with `--no-vacuum`?

Comment: Check [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "--no-vacuum" helped. The db is not complete yet, pgbench is creating primary keys right now. However, PG and disk show a lot of activity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rather than viewing the very slow vacuum as a problem, perhaps you could view it as an opportunity to learn what it will be like to work with a 20 TB database.  If all you want to do is burden the back-up system, you can just throw some large garbage into the directory $PGDATA/base/<nnnnn>/.  I think most backup tools don't bother to validate the files they copy are a legitimate part of the database before copying them.

Comment: "What's worse, there does not seem to be much activity with either postmaster process or disk (I tested that with iotop)."  I certainly can't replicate this.  The disks are working just as hard for the vacuuming as they were for the COPY.  But it takes about twice as long when entirely disk bound, as there is twice as much to do (it has to read and write everything, rather than just write everything)

Comment: @jjanes Sorry, it turned out today that underlying NFS connection failed for unknown reason (yes, it's NFS but mounted on fast storage). (and the decision to use NFS is not dependent on me)

Answer (score 1):

It will take a long time to create a 15 TB database (I found [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/a-formula-to-calculate-pgbench-scaling-factor-for-target-db-size/) useful for estimating the database size).

If you left the database at default settings, I am not surprised if it takes a long time. To speed up `VACUUM`, set `max_parallel_mainenance_workers` and `maintenance_work_mem` high (but it will still take a long time).

Comment: I'm confused - would it not be better to switch autovacuum off completely for data loading? Also, set no-logging? Then, after initialisation, take a  backup, then set the tables to logged and switch on autovacuum? Then run a benchmark for x hours and then do a pitr using the first backup and the WAL? Would this not be a possibility for the OP?

Comment: Also, separate disks for data and indexes? Maybe even separate tables?

Comment: @Verace Separating tables and indexes is an old myth that refuses to die. But I agree that turning off autovacuum while you load will help. As far as I know, turning an unlogged table into a logged one will write everything to WAL, so the savings are unclear. And running pgbench with unlogged tables will make the test even more unrealistic than pgbench is anyway.

Comment: Surely some sort of RAID is advisable? I found your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54511321/470530) - so, when a table is changed to LOGGED, you're saying that WALs are written for the entire table on a block by block basis? But, what if you'd just taken a backup? I also found [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195780/set-postgresql-table-to-logged-after-data-loadingthis]. It appears that **unless** the initialisation can be performed in a single transaction, it's not possible! I'm not sure why - a full backup would mean that you'd have no problem with **only** new WALs?

Comment: If you could take an LVM snapshot or ZFS one (on a cold system), you'd be able to apply new WALs without worrying about the "older" data and it would be quicker - **if** the OP has the disk space? This appears to me to be a flaw in PostgreSQL - not being able to tell PostgreSQL to dispense with WAL? In any case, thanks for getting back to me and your input!

Comment: @Vérace You can call it a flaw in PostgreSQL. However, the philosophy of the project (as far as I have any insight into it) is to err on the side of caution and *not* to offer features that make it easy for people to wreck their database. And telling the database "I have just made a snapshot, now turn that table into a logged one without writing it to WAL" would be exactly such a feature. If you find a way to do this with little or no risk for the user to hurt themselves, go ahead and propose it to pgsql-hackers!

Comment: You are far too modest Herr Albe! :-) Anyone whose name appears [here](https://www.postgresql.org/community/contributors/) has more than a passing insight into the project! Superusers can do all sorts of stuff that could wreck a db - with great power comes great responsibility... &c. In any case, the whole *nix philosophy has always been grounded in a "give the user a gun with no mechanism to stop themselves shooting at their foot!" attitude. I will try to find the time to continue this on the lists - I believe we're straying off-topic and long chats are frowned upon here! MfG...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have a question for you on "Separating tables and indexes is an old myth that refuses to die. " https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/separating-tables-and-indexes-in-postgresql-possibly-in-general-as-well

I'm very curious how can you explain this issue.

Comment: Well, you can often hear DBAs advocate to put tables and indexes on different disks, because it improves performance. The truth behind that is that spreading I/O over several devices will spread the load, but it is much better to do that by striping on a lower level. Indexes and tables may have different I/O characteristics, but in these days of solid state drives, it makes no difference whatsoever. Plus, in PostgreSQL you need to create a tablespace to separate them, and tablespaces are an additional maintenance burden.