# Separating tables and indexes in Postgresql (possibly in general as well)

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization

Popularly separation of tables and indexes and putting them on different disks is supposed to improve performance.

Does anybody has some *evidence* on performance, pros and cons of either solution?

Can you please answer following questions:

1. How *precisely* this is implemented (I want to know details of the scenario)?
2. Why is it not working as claimed in popular recipe (if so, of course)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Well.. I meant getting some evidence rather than opinion on the subject.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Rephrased.